# How to click on the Acknowledge Button using Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I have an Acknowledge button and I want to click it. I have tried all the three methods listed below. But it is not working.

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.btn.btn.primary")).submit();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='content']/div[2]/div/input")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@value='I Acknowledge' ")).click();
```

This is the HTML Of the page:

```
<input class="btn btn-primary" type="button" value="I Acknowledge">
```

Comment: Post the HTML of the element you wish to click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To click on the **I Acknowledge** element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input.btn.btn-primary[value='I Acknowledge']"))).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@class='btn btn-primary' and @value='I Acknowledge']"))).click();
  ```

Comment: Thank you the above code worked, I appreciate it. I was struggling with it for a while

Answer (score 0):

Try with this css locator:

input[class='btn btn-primary'][value='I Acknowledge']

Comment: I tried it but still its not working    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[class='btn btn-primary'][value='I Acknowledge']")).submit(); both with click or either submit  its not working ...

Comment: Try javascript executor ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);

Comment: i tried javascript executor both with css selector and xpath but still its not working WebElement element=  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[@class='btn btn-sm btn-primary' and text()='No'']")));
          
          // WebElement element =  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("button.btn.btn-sm.btn-primary[data-ng-click*='attemptNext']")));
                    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
            js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);